# MacOS: two Perl installs: "Dumper.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched"

Tags: macos, perl, homebrew

I am labouring since a while, to get rid of a conflict between the system Perl (MacOS, Catalina: v5.18.4) and the Homebrew Perl (v5.30.1). The modules are installed in `~/perl5`

But I am realising, that also the system Perl uses for the modules `~/perl5`

Here are some infos from my Shell (zsh):

```
which perl
/usr/local/bin/perl
ls -l /usr/local/bin/perl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mstep  admin  30 11 Jan 19:17 /usr/local/bin/perl -> ../Cellar/perl/5.30.1/bin/perl
```

Thats the Perl from Homebrew (v5.30.1). Some other infos from the System-Perl and

```
env | grep PERL
PERL5LIB=/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/Users/mstep/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base "/Users/mstep/perl5"
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/Users/mstep/perl5

/usr/bin/perl -V
...
%ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5"
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/Users/mstep/perl5"
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/Users/mstep/perl5""
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/mstep/perl5"
  @INC:
    /Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/5.18.4
    /Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5
    /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.18
...

perl -e 'print join("\n",@INC)'
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.1
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.1
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.1/lib/perl5/5.30.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.1/lib/perl5/5.30.1
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.1
```

In my `.zshrc` file I tried everything to no avail; just for now, I commented everything out:

```
# PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=$HOME/perl5" cpan local::lib
# eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5)"
# eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
# PATH="/Users/mstep/perl5/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; export PATH;
# PERL5LIB="/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;
# PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/Users/mstep/perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:+:${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
# PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/Users/mstep/perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
# PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/mstep/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
# PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/mstep/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
# PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=$HOME/perl5" cpan local::lib
```

Every time I am starting my ZSH it starts with installing `Running install for module 'local::lib'` and ZSH is complaining, that `YAML` is not installed, finishing with the following error; if I leave some lines of `perl5`-definition in my `.zshrc` it is even issuing this error twice:

```
Dumper.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xc500080, needed 0xc400080)
```

How to *educate* the system perl, to use the right module folder? I would be very grateful for any help!

marek

ps: Thx for your answers:

```
find /Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5 -name '*Dumper*' /Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/PPIx/Regexp/Dumper.pm
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/PPIx/QuoteLike/Dumper.pm
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/Module/Build/Dumper.pm
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/.meta/Data-Dumper-2.173
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Data/Dumper
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.bundle
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBI/ProfileDumper.pm
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/DataDumper.pm
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBI/ProfileDumper
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Data/Dumper.pm
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/YAML/Dumper.pm
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/YAML/Dumper.pod
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/YAML/Dumper
/Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5/PPI/Dumper.pm
```

Comment: Maybe the conflicts could be avoided by using `perlbrew` instead of Homebrew? See [this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15165986). By the way, why is `zsh` trying to install `local::lib` ?

Comment: Try: “conda install perl”.  This installs Perl in a relatively isolated environment. Multiple installations do not clash.

Comment: That means that one build of Perl is loading modules installed by a different build. It's weird that you are getting this because different arch dirs are being used (`perl5/5.30.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level` vs `perl5/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level`)

Comment: What's the output of `find /Users/mstep/perl5/lib/perl5 -name 'Dumper*'`? Do you have permissions to write files to `/usr/local/Cellar/`?

Comment: Thx for your answers: I edited my original question, to answer ikegami. Yes writing permissions, of course in `/usr/local/Cellar`

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue, so thought I'd post the solution here as I couldn't find it anywhere.

The issue was a broken `cpanm` install (recipe?) from `brew` - the first line of which (the shebang of `/usr/local/bin/cpanm`) was using the system perl.

I had to run

```
brew reinstall cpanm
```

because the problem is now fixed in that recipe, though the version was not bumped.

I could then reinstall my perl modules (e.g. `cpanm --reinstall JSON::XS`) to get things working.